# jQuery - .length returning "number is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm still learning so I apologise if this is a silly question!

Basically I'm trying to get the number of elements in my page with a certain class.  My searching tells me I need to use .length but it's not working for some reason.

Any ideas at a quick glance at what may be causing the issue?

```
var item = $('.item')
var itemWidth = item.width();
var numberItems = item.length();
console.log(numberItems);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just `item.length` - the `length` property is a number, and you're trying to call it as a function, so you get that error.

Now `width` is a function; you may be looking for `.height()`. The `length` property tells you how many elements matched the selector (more generally, the size of the jQuery collection). DOM elements are measured by width and height (`.width()` and `.height()`, along with `.innerWidth()`, `.innerHeight()`, `.outerWidth()`, and `.outerHeight()`).

Comment: Brilliant!  This was driving me insane.  Baby steps I guess! Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: This solved my problem. To clarify, in Java it's `string.length()`, in JavaScript it's `string.length`.